# accidentally loaded schema into the actual postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just did this:

```
    my_db=> \c postgres
    postgres=> alter table my_db rename to my_db_27032011;
    ALTER DATABASE
    postgres=> create database my_db
    CREATE DATABASE
    postgres=> \i my_fixed_db_schema.sql
    CREATE TABLE
    ALTER TABLE
    INSERT
    INSERT
    ....

    postgres=>
```

See the mistake? This would be fine if my_db was small, but it's not - it's over a thousand tables, with constraints and triggers all over the place.

Any clues as to how I can undo this? I don't have a backup of the postgres db itself because, well, what sort of idiot would break that?

It's probably not going to affect day-to-day running, as the actual postgres tables are (probably) intact. It's just messy and I'd like to fix it, but without re-installing the entire server.

Comment: Is there anything in the postgres db that prevents you from dropping and recreating it?

Comment: lack of knowledge of what should be in it, and fear of the impact if I get it wrong...

Comment: oh, wait - I think I see what you're asking. "Probably not", is the more intelligent answer. If it doesn't impact my working my_db, then that would be the ideal solution

Comment: There is nothing special about the postgres db apart from some utilities expecting it to exist.

Comment: ok - then I'll get a dump from someone elses (very similar) machine, and see how that goes... ta.